# Remove rows using two columns

Tags: r

Using this option it is possible to remove data which exist in a dataframe using the values from another dataframe:

```
df1[!(df1$name %in% df2$name),]
```

If there is a second columnin which I would like to take into consideration for removal prose example in df1 there is the column name and id and the same in df2 how is it possible to check the values in both columns?
trial example `df1[!([df1$name & df1$id] %in% [df2$name & df2$id]),]`

Comment: do you have both datasets of same number of rows..   Perhaps `anti_join(df1, df2, by = c('name', 'id'))`

Comment: @akrun no they are not the same number of rows. If they are there wasn't the need to remove something

Comment: try with `anti_join` as it is not clear without an example

Comment: In `base R`, you can also do `df1[!(paste(df1$name, df1$id) %in% paste(df2$name, df2$id)),]`

Answer (score 2):

We can use

```
df1[!(paste(df1$name, df1$id) %in% paste(df2$name, df2$id)),]
```

Or with `anti_join`

```
library(dplyr)
anti_join(df1, df2, by = c('name', 'id'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you were trying to do:

```
df1[!(df1$name %in% df2$name & df1$id %in% df2$id),]
```

Answer (score 0):

lets see what happened in this basic example:

```
R> 1:10 %in% 3:6
 [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

so this approach results in a vector where each of the elements 1:10 is checked against elements 3:6

Though this is a compact and awesome vectorized thingy , is it rarely directly useful for data frame operations -where all the vectors are stacked as columns. Join operations may be a much more straight forward approach for this in your case - anti_join.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you had a chance to look at [answer] for guidance on answering SO questions? It would be helpful if your answer not only discussed how a function works but  how it answered the question reproducibly.